# Indexer is out-of-bounds error. Using df loc and iloc to get the column value that meets a specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
>>> df
         Status    server Name   Location                    DateTime
0     [RUNNING]        server1     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
1     [RUNNING]      server07a     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
2     [RUNNING]      server07b     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
3     [RUNNING]    labserver01     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
4  [NOTRUNNING]      server04a     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
5  [NOTRUNNING]      server04b     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
6     [RUNNING]       server05     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
7     [RUNNING]       server06     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
8     [RUNNING]       server08     London  2021-02-08 16:55:43.770558
```

Am trying to fetch the names of server who have status as NOTRUNNING. The verify variable is supposed to be filled with a list of 'None' per entry if everything show RUNNING. If there is an item that says NOTRUNNING then instead of NONE, it is supposed to write the serverName.

```
def errorstatuschecker(df):
   affectedserver = []
   #print(df)
   for i in df['Status'].values:
      if i != '[RUNNING]':
         for j in range(len(df.index)):
            print(df.loc[df['Status'] == '[RUNNING]', 'server Name'].iloc[j])
      else:
         affectedserver.append('None')
   verify = len(affectedserver) > 0 and all(elem == affectedserver[0] for elem in affectedserver)
```

I get the below error. I understand why. But I am not able to understand how to write this better so I don't run out of indexes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1501, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1444, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
idx = df.index[df['Status']=="[NOTRUNNING]"].tolist()
df.loc[idx]
```

I think it will be running faster. If you just want to save the servers names in a new dataframe just:

```
df2 = df['server Name'].loc[idx]
```

Comment: Thank you! This also helps. Not exactly for the scenario that I using now. But this serves the purpose for a pretty similar operation too.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to navigate around and still get what I wanted. Might not be very smart. but works for now. Any better way is still welcome.

```
def errorstatuschecker(df):
   affectedserver = list(df.loc[df['Status'] != '[RUNNING]', 'server Name'].to_numpy())
   if len(affectedserver) == 0:
      msg = errormessages.msg6
      notify(msg)
   else:
      affectedsystems = '\n'.join(map(str, affectedserver))
      msg = errormessages.msg1
      subject = errormessages.sub1
      notify(msg,affectedsystems)
```